# Remove duplicate images from media library.

Tags: images, media-library, duplicates

I recently used an image importer that has duplicated all the images. They are attached to the right posts and the posts are fine (not duplicated).

How do I run through my media library deleting duplicate images?

Answer (score 2):

I know its too late for this answer, but can help others, you can use Media Deduper plugin to index and find duplicated image , it is also good enough to link the post to existing image.

Answer (score 0):

The best way (if the duplicated images are the ones attached) is to order by date, and bulk delete all the older ones.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you expand on your answer, please? Do I do this via the wordpress admin or creating a loop?

Comment: Go to the media library, order the files by date, and delete all them old ones.

Comment: They all have the same date as they were all "edited" at the same time. There are 1000+ images.